# How to display certain values on one column via OBIEE?

Tags: oracle11g, repository, business-intelligence, obiee

I have a report using a dashboard, and I have one field which has all the countries. What I need to do is displaying just certain countries from this field not all of them. 
I would highly appreciate you if you can give me the steps to display some countries not all of them from the same field.

Answer (score 1):

You can [specify a filter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10544/analyses.htm#i1009045) in the report criteria. You can also use Selection Steps, through the [Selection Steps dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10544/filter.htm#BGBDDFIG), or interactively when viewing the report and using the [Right-click menu for data views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10544/appuir.htm#CHDFHDBE)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a filter on country column in your analysis and select which countries you want to display

Shiva